# Flutter how to hide focused menu child when menu appears and show it when it desappears

Tags: flutter, dart, menu

I'm using [focused_menu](https://pub.dev/packages/focused_menu) as menu inside actions in the appBar to be able to customize items background color.
I've modifed the `offset` to hide the actions icon when the focued menu appears but the icon is still visible how can I fix it ?

**What I have**

[image]

**What I would like to have**

[image]

**Here's the code**

```
class TestMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestMenu({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestMenu> createState() => _TestMenuState();
}

class _TestMenuState extends State<TestMenu> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FocusedMenuHolder(
      menuWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
      blurBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      blurSize: 0,
      menuOffset: -50,
      openWithTap: true,
      child: Icon(
        Icons.more_vert,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
      menuItems: [
        FocusedMenuItem(
          title: Row(
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.science,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 12,),
                Text(
                  "Lab",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ]
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          onPressed: () {
            print("Lab clicked");
          },
        ),
        FocusedMenuItem(
            title: Row(
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.settings,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 12,),
                Text(
                  "Settings",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ]
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              print("Settings clicked");
            },
        ),
        FocusedMenuItem(
          title: Row(
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.share,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 12,),
                Text(
                  "Share",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ]
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            print("Share clicked");
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I've tried to wrap `FocusedMenuHolder` inside `Visbility` but it doesn't works because click on the child Icon make appears the focused menu and it will change both visibility at the same time, it means menu disappears Icon too